# Deciding whether a day in the calendar is a holiday

Tags: google-apps-script, calendar

Regional public holidays can be displayed in the Google calendar. If I turn on holidays in a region, I can see the address of the calendar I'm using:

```
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('hu.hungarian#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com');
var now = new Date();
var events = cal.getEventsForDay(now);
...
```

However, this only works as long as the feature is turned on in the calendar. Otherwise, "cal" will be null.
How can I eliminate this error?

Comment: what language is this...?

Comment: @GergelyCsáky, I think MoldOfDestiny wants to know the _programming_ language. Please [edit] your question and add an appropriate language tag.

Comment: It is indeed possible. :) The above problem occurred while running a Google script.